# Load but ignore URL in HTML

Tags: html

I need to access a URL to log the user out before rendering the rest of the HTML page (the page needs to ensure the user is logged out). The contents of the URL are not important; as soon as I hit the URL the user's logged out and I can proceed.

Right now I'm doing this by including the URL as a `<LINK>`:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8000/accounts/logout/">
</head>
```

Is this a reasonable approach or is there a better way?

Comment: You have no guarantee about the order in which head entries are processed. So in case you have code included in the head make sure it waits until the logout has occurred (however). I would prefer a routine that calls the logout, checks the result (http headers) and reaises an event that can trigger the rest of the page to start, though that depends on javascript.

Comment: What I don't understand: if that really is a static html page (otherwise you could do the logout request in the script generating the dynamic page), then why should it interest if the user is logged in or not? Because the page contains references to objects affected by an existing session?

Comment: arkascha, this is a bit of an odd setup: it's a static page on a mobile app that logs the user out, then logs them back in by posting a form. I'm attempting to use as little javascript on there as I can (eg. I'm not including jquery) and therefore wanted a simple html based option if there was a reasonable one.

Comment: You want to autologout the user without asking and force him to enter his credentials again? Hm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this is to use the image preloading function of JavaScript to make a request to the logout url. In the `<head>` add:

```
<script>
 logout = new Image(); 
 logout.src = "http://localhost:8000/accounts/logout/";
</script>
```

That way you don't have to abuse the `<link>` tag for it, but it does mean you have to rely on JavaScript.

Comment: That's an interesting idea - in fact just accessing the page as an img that's not displayed might be a good way to go about it.